# When was NSS (Name Service Switch) introduced in Solaris?

Tags: solaris, history, nsswitch

I was not able to find a date or a Solaris release number... Also, beside Ultrix's svc.conf system (mentionned in [NSS's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_Service_Switch)), did other comparable systems exist in other Unices, before NSS?

Comment: It was there since at least Solaris 2.1, so may always have been in Solaris 2.  http://www.boudnik.org/~cos/stuff/solaris2/Q4.1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Name Service Switch was introduced in Solaris 2.0, which [shipped in June 1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Solaris#Version_history).